# Make timestamp appear in log file automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am using python 3.7 logging module. This is how it is configured.

```
import logging
import os

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s-%(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
fh = logging.FileHandler(os.getcwd() + "/log/" + os.path.basename(__file__) + ".log")
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

The code works fine. However, I want timestamps to be added to each row of entry in the log file.

Currently, if I run `logger.info("new log entry")`, the log file will have a new line added that looks like this;

`new log entry`

What I want is to have timestamp prepended on each new line added to the log file to look something like this;

`2020-04-22 11:11:16 new log entry`

How do I configure the logger to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure the `FileHandler` logger in the same way you configured the `StreamHandler`:

```
fh = logging.FileHandler(os.getcwd() + "/log/" + os.path.basename(__file__) + ".log")
fh.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
fh_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s-%(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(fh_formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Tested to work successfully.